# Comparing with Nothing is not the same of comparing with a variable containing Nothing

Tags: vb.net, equals

I have this strange behavior of VB.

I need to check if a `SingleOrDefault()` on a **KeyValuePair collection** found what I was searching for.

So:

```
Dim revProp As KeyValuePair(Of IKeyInterfaceType, IValueInterfaceType) = 
                                 revisionProperties.SingleOrDefault(Function(kvp) ...)
```

In C# I would then write:

```
if (revProp.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<IKeyInterfaceType,IValueInterfaceType>)))
```

`Nothing` is the VB equivalent for C#'s `default`, in fact if I write

```
Dim emptyRevProp As KeyValuePair(Of IKeyInterfaceType, IValueInterfaceType) = Nothing
```

and then look at `emptyRevProp` in QuickWatch, I see a KeyValuePair with null key and value.

If I then compare the two structs with `Equals`:

```
revProp.Equals(emptyRevProp)
```

I correctly get `True` if `SingleOrDefault()` found nothing in the collection satisfying supplied condition.

But, here it comes the matter, if I write:

```
revProp.Equals(Nothing)
```

I get False.

Why is this?

Comment: _"Nothing is the VB equivalent for C#'s default"_ No, in VB.NET it is more, it is the default value and it's `null`.

Comment: That's the same thing as I said, because `null` is in effect the default value of reference types.

Comment: I assume that `revProp.Equals(Nothing)` calls `Object.Equals` which just detects reference equality. The compiler sees `Nothing` and does not know that it should be a `KeyValuePair(Of IKeyInterfaceType, IValueInterfaceType)`. That's the difference to  `revProp.Equals(emptyRevProp)` where the argument is clearly a `KeyValuePair(Of IKeyInterfaceType, IValueInterfaceType)` that  overrides `Equals`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dts52z7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Probably the closest to obtain the same result is `revProp.Equals(CType(Nothing, KeyValuePair(Of IKeyInterfaceType, IValueInterfaceType)))`

Comment: Yes, but that would be pointless since it's much more readable to declare it with the correct type.

Comment: Yeah, I see. The answer is probably your second comment. Since it does not overrides the Equals, the compare is not valid. I ended up making a static readonly instance of an empty KVP.

Comment: As i've linked, it does override it. But the argument has to be of the same type and value. And `Nothing` is <> `KeyValuePair(Of IKeyInterfaceType, IValueInterfaceType)`. That's why it returns `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VB.NET `Nothing` can be `null` or `default`. In this case it's just treated as `null`/`Nothing`. But `Nothing` is not `KeyValuePair(Of IKeyInterfaceType, IValueInterfaceType)`. Therefore [`ValueType.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dts52z7(v=vs.110).aspx)(which overrides `Object.Equals`) returns `False`. The argument is not the correct type, so it cannot be equal. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dts52z7(v=vs.110).aspx):

> true if obj and this instance **are the same type** and represent the same
>   value; otherwise, false.

The [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/valuetype.cs#d8b9b308e644b983#references)  is even more clear:

```
public override bool Equals (Object obj) {
    if (null==obj) {
        return false;  // <---- !!!!!!!!!
    }
    RuntimeType thisType = (RuntimeType)this.GetType();
    RuntimeType thatType = (RuntimeType)obj.GetType();

    if (thatType!=thisType) {
        return false;
    }

    // omitting value comparison  ...
}
```

When you use

```
revProp.Equals(emptyRevProp)
```

It can compare the values with each other, hence it returns true.

You could use  `Nothing` as `default` in this way:

```
revProp.Equals(CType(Nothing, KeyValuePair(Of IKeyInterfaceType, IValueInterfaceType)))
```

But that would be less readable than declaring it as the correct type in the first place.